# Identity with efcore for customer and staff

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I currently design table for customer and staff for my ecommerce app and I am using asp.net core identity. I want to know if I should use 1 table user (aka aspnetuser) for staff and customer or should I separate them and use user id as foreign key? If separating them 2 new table with foreign key is user id, how can I use user manager for creating account for staff and customer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the base `IdentityUser` class in order to create a table with additional fields, like:

```
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
...
```

where the `Type` field could be `Staff` or `Customer`.

Or you can use one or more additional table and use the `Id` as defined in **IdentityUser** class from *Microsoft.ASpNetCore.Identity*:

```
    public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="IdentityUser{TKey}"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public IdentityUser() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="IdentityUser{TKey}"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The user name.</param>
        public IdentityUser(string userName) : this()
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the primary key for this user.
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
...
```

you can define the type of your `Id` field, like my previous example, and use the same type on a related field (like `IdentityUserId`) in your custom table/tables.

If you extend the base `IdentityUser` class you need to create a derived context with this declaration, like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Contexts
{
    public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<MyIdentityUser>
    {
...
```

Comment: Do you think should I use TPH for this type of problem? And how about using role ?

Comment: Role is another solution. In that case you don't need anymore the `Type` field in your derived IdentityUser class, but filtering is harder. I use role for authorization scopes, not for profiling scopes. I prefer to use separated _entity_ for personal data and IdentityUser + IdentityRole only for authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thanks Babyface_Developer. Don't forget to accept the answer if it is ok for you. Thank you.